Weird ds18b20 behaviors on ESP32 micropython
The sensors seem to be somehow flipping from non working to working over long periods of time, sometimes right after poweron or maybe after 3 days of working completely fine. 1 or 2 sensors will usually drop out lasting even after reconnecting power multiple times, reflashing or using another ds18b20 library. But they always come back to normal after a enough reconnects. One sensor also sometimes gets offset constantly by like 2 degrees instead of dropping out. Ive also noticed that on some powerups the first read will sometimes give a temperature of like 150 or 80 degrees for one reading the go back to normal.
In my setup right now i have 8 sensors in a star network configuration, even though the total length of each sensor is under 1m I'm still getting these silly results. They are running of an lolin 32 with a 4K7 resistor from 3.3V to DQ. Im very certain noting is loose and that there is not a bad connection anywhere.
The sensors im guessing are not original since the dont have the serial 28 and 00 00 that dallas/maxim uses though i got mine from a local reputable store so i would be a bit surprised if they sold me half-way defect sensors. They are made by Shelly which seem like a proper company.
Im not really expecting anyone to be able to reproduce any of my problems, especially since i cant find anyone else who has the same issue but if anyone any tips on what i should try to fix this would be much appreciated.
If its not the sensors then it seems to me that it must be that the signal integrity is really bad maybe? but i cant really see how that would be true if it persists for so long.
I used to store the whole serial but started only saving the last 6 bytes after the the bytes from the sixth to the eight byte kept showing the same behavoiur, suddenly changing for no reason and staying that way for long periods of time as if the sensor itself flipped its own serial for a while somehow (even though thats impossible?).
I've tried a stronger pullup about 2k but this still didnt fix anything.
I've been able to get the error to happen with the code below, but ive also gotten it when using uasyncio library:
import machine, onewire, time, ds18x20
from machine import Pin

s = 0
scratch = 0
ds_pin = Pin(19)
ds_sensor = ds18x20.DS18X20(onewire.OneWire(ds_pin))

while True:
    roms = None
    roms = ds_sensor.scan()
    length = len(roms)        
    ds_sensor.convert_temp()
    time.sleep_ms(375)
    print('Devices:',length)


    for rom in roms:
        hexaddr = ''

        if scratch < 0:
            ds.wrie_scratch(rom, b'\x00\x00\x5f')
        
        hexaddr = hex(int.from_bytes(rom, 'little'))    
        hexaddr = hexaddr[-6:]
        celcius = ds_sensor.read_temp(rom)
        
        print(hexaddr, ds_sensor.read_temp(rom))
        s += celcius 
        
        
    scratch = 1
    
    print('avg = ',s / length,'\n')
    s = 0
    time.sleep(30)

The output i get when all 8 are detected and address is not trunqated:
I have put the readout of each sensor when only 7 are detected underneath the proper ones. Yo
Devices: 8

0x4070d446f10528 24.1875
0xdc2e24d446603928 24.5625
0xe479e0d446108e28 24.1875
0xd8299fd446b45628 24.4375
0x8656bed446ccc628 24.625
0xce6954d44665ba28 24.1875
0x343891d44692da28 24.0
0x533257d446682828 24.25

Output when only 7 are detected:

0x4070d446f10528 24.4375
0xdc2e24d446603928 24.9375
0xe479e0d446108e28 24.625
0xd8299fd546b45628 27.4375
0x8646bed446ccc628 25.0
0xce6954d44665ba28 24.375
0x533257d446680828 24.75

I have put the readout of each sensor when only 7 are detected underneath the proper ones. Note that the fourth, fifth and eight sensors have their serial changed. This change is always consistent when the error occurs, it always changes to the same wrong vaule.

0x4070d446f10528 24.1875

0x4070d446f10528

0xdc2e24d446603928 24.5625

0xdc2e24d446603928

0xe479e0d446108e28 24.1875

0xe479e0d446108e28

0xd8299fd446b45628 24.4375

0xd8299fd546b45628

0x8656bed446ccc628 24.625

0x8646bed446ccc628

0xce6954d44665ba28 24.1875

0xce6954d44665ba28

0x343891d44692da28 24.0

this sensor is not detected

0x533257d446682828 24.25

0x533257d446680828



Did you notice that time.sleep_ms(375) is much shorter than the recommended value? In the below sources, 750 ms is advised. Have you tried using that value?
https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/tutorial/onewire.html
https://mpython.readthedocs.io/en/v2.2.1/library/mPython/ds18x20.html

The 375ms is from the datasheet, since im using a 11 bit resolution and not 12 bit. Even so i have already experimented with different conversion timings with no luck.

I do not know if you can trust specifications in the datasheet of original manufacturer, because the devices you are using are not genuine ones.  A README in the famous github repositorycounterfeit_DS18B20 suggests that the hardware design of your devices may be different from those of the original ones.
That said, if tinkering the conditions (waiting times, pull-ups, etc.) with your parts was not successful, buy genuine ones.
